# How can I preserve leading white space in PDF export of reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I have some leagacy reporting data which is accessed from SSRS via an xml web service data source. The service returns one big field containing formatted plain text.

I've been able to preserve white space in the output by replacing space chars with a non-breaking space, however, when exporting to PDF leading white space is not preserved on lines that do not begin with a visible character. So a report that should render like this:

```
          Report Title
Name      Sales
Bob       100.00
Wendy     199.50
```

Is rendered like this:

```
Report Title               (leading white space stripped on this line)
Name      Sales            (intra-line white space is preserved)
Bob       100.00
Wendy     199.50
```

I've not been able to find any solution other than prefixing each line with a character which I really don't want to do.

Using SQL 2005 SP3

Answer (score 4):

I googled and googled the answer to this question.  Many answers included changing spaces to Chr(20) or Chr(160).  I found a simple solution that seems to work.

1. If your leading spaces come from a tab stop replace "/t" with actual spaces, 5 or so
   string newString = oldString.Replace("/t","     ")
2. In the expression field for the textbox I found that simply adding a null "Chr(0)" at the beginning of the string preserves the leading spaces.

Example:

```
=Chr(0) & "My Text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried non-breaking spaces of the ASCII variety?

`=Replace(Fields!Report.Value, " ", chr(160))`

I use `chr(160)` to keep phone numbers together (12 345 6789). In your case you may want to only replace leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding property of the textbox containing the text. Padding on the left can be increased to add space that does not get stripped on output.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this work around:

- In the Textbox properties select the alignment tab.
- In the Padding option section edit the right or left padding(wherever you need to add space).

If you need to conditionally indent the text you can use the expression as well.